# Inserting a function with arguments to appendToGlobalCtors

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I want to insert a function call that executes before anything else in the program. I figured the way to do this is to insert to the global constructors with appendToGlobalCtors() in this way:

```
LLVMContext &C = M.getContext();
Function* FInit = Function::Create(FunctionType::get(Type::getVoidTy(C), false), GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage, INITMEMORY, &M);
appendToGlobalCtors(M, FInit, 0);
```

This works well if the function has no arguments. But what if the function I need to insert has arguments that I would like to specify? How do I create the function to insert into the global constructors? The function I have returns void. I already know how to use the IRBuilder to create a function call. But the builder takes the arguments in the builder.CreateCall(Func, FuncArgs). How do I do this and append it to the global constructors?

Hope I was clear enough. Let me know if this needs more clarification.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way this is possible is when your arguments are constant, obviously. In this case just wrap your call into another function and mark it `__attribute__((constructor))`:

```
void foo(int x, int y)
{
...
}

__attribute__((constructor))
void bar()
{
foo(1,2);
}
```